open local website from a ContainerNet server (VM)
Today I am facing this error, mainly due to my lack of experience.
My idea was to use ContainerNet to deploy a Docker network, with a Docker server image, showing a basic website (Flask used).
My host is in Windows, so, in order to use ContainerNet I set up a Ubuntu VM.
The code is here:
from mininet.net import Containernet
from mininet.node import Controller
from mininet.cli import CLI
from mininet.link import TCLink
from mininet.log import info, setLogLevel

setLogLevel('info')

net = Containernet(controller=Controller)
net.addController('c0')

info('*** Adding server and client container\n')
server = net.addDocker('server', ip='10.0.0.251', ports=[80], port_bindings={80:3000},dcmd="python app.py", dimage="test_server:latest", publish_all_ports=True)
client = net.addDocker('client', ip='10.0.0.252', dimage="test_client:latest")

info('*** Setup network\n')
s1 = net.addSwitch('s1')
s2 = net.addSwitch('s2')

net.addLink(server, s1)
net.addLink(s1, s2, cls=TCLink, delay='100ms', bw=1)
net.addLink(s2, client)
net.start()

CLI(net)

net.stop()

By looking at the code, I specified the server IP, the port bindings and the publish_all_ports parameter to True
No error while executing the code, the output of the dump command from the Mininet CLI is this:
<Docker server: server-eth0:10.0.0.251 pid=66552> 
<Docker client: client-eth0:10.0.0.252 pid=66651> 
<OVSSwitch s1: lo:127.0.0.1,s1-eth1:None,s1-eth2:None pid=66703> 
<OVSSwitch s2: lo:127.0.0.1,s2-eth1:None,s2-eth2:None pid=66706> 
<Controller c0: 127.0.0.1:6653 pid=66477> 

However, if I go to Firefox (still inside the VM, not on Windows) to the 10.0.0.251:3000 address, nothing appears.
Nor 10.0.0.251:80.
The docker ps -a command shows a container named server with the correct ports binding.
I am quite sure there's a piece in the puzzle that I am missing.
May someone give me an help?
